# Some file formats not downloading in iOS

Tags: ios, download, nsdata, nsurl

I'm trying to download a file which doesn't have a 'normal' extension, i.e. it's made by our company. Let's call it ".abc".

If I put a file url on the FTP called www.fakewebsite.com/mycontent.abc

```
NSString *stringURL = @"www.fakewebsite.com/mycontent.abc";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSLog(@"%@", urlData);
```

urlData returns null.

If I change that extension from .abc to .swf, .rtf, .zip, etc.. the url data returns values. Does anyone know what I should be searching for to do this for ".abc"? If not, I guess i'll have to just wrap our company file in a .zip which isn't ideal.

If anyone could even just put me on the right path i'd be grateful but i've been googling around and i'm either asking the wrong question or this is a really rare scenario.

Thanks very much :)

edit:

where i'm at now

```
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.fakewebsite.com/mycontent.abc"]];
[postRequest setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0];
    theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
    if (!theConnection) {
        receivedData = nil;
    }
```

The data is being written with:

```
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"test12345.txt"];
[receivedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"%@", filePath);
```

It's writing to a .txt for debugging purposes, usually i'd want to write it to .abc. When I checked the .txt, I got the error code 405 html page:

HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed. Internet Information Services (IIS).

This leads me to believe it is finding it, it just doesn't know what to do with it. Any more ideas?

Comment: Use `NSURLConnection` instead and try with `Content-Type = @"text/html"`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I'm reading on doing downloading now with NSURLConnection. After i've finished, where would I be looking to put that Content-Type = @"text/html"?

Comment: Search for `NSURLConnection` related answer, and you will find in details.

Comment: Hey, I tried it. still doesn't seem to be working, i outputted what I was getting to a .txt file and i got the : 405 HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed. Internet Information Services (IIS).

Comment: i've updated my question if you could lead me to anymore help

Comment: Copy and paste url which you want to access in Simulator/Device safari browser. If page is not open than you need permission from network administrator to access the link.

Comment: Thanks so much Kampai, I just asked a senior dev here and he said it won't work because there's no MIME type for it on the ftp

Comment: You didn't answer really so all I can do is upvote all your comments

Comment: It's my pleasure. Welcome :)